# Установка телефона на Ubuntu

Tags: pop3, x11, телефония, ubuntu

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как установить на Ubuntu 11.10 телефон для звонков на городские телефоны (виртуальный), аналогичный на Widows?

Спасибо.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что ничего общего с программированием.

Answer (score 1):

Софтфон поставить, в смысле? Мне [twikle](http://www.twinklephone.com/) нравится. Есть еще [Ekiga](http://ekiga.org/screenshots), но у нее настроек меньше, если это важно. Подразумевается, что вы знаете, как подключиться к оператору предоставляющему данную услугу.

```
aptitude install twinkle
```

Answer (score 0):

поднимаем сервер ip телефонии на ОС - Asterisk - более стабильный. Находим 3G модем - от МТС Голосовой модуль по умолчанию активирован только в модемах МТС.Для других можно активировать опцию.

Рекомендованное ядро Linux 2.6.33+ Asterisk 1.6.+ USB 2.0

Ставим софтфон - мне лично нравится "X-Lite"

подробнее - <a rel="nofollow" href="http://asterisk-pbx.ru/wiki/doku.php/new2">тут</a>